# Floating-point error when calling dll function from VBA

Tags: vba, dll, overflow, fpu

Here is the situation. I am using MS Visual Sturio 2005 and Excel 2007. I create a dll containing a function

```
extern "C" VARIANT WINAPI MyFunc()
{
  VARIANT res;
  memset(&res, 0, sizeof(VARIANT));
  ::VariantInit(&res);    
  return res;
}
```

That is called from Excel VBA. This function seems to work correctly.
But there is a problem: when VBA returns from my function and tries to execute the next floating point instruction I see a window:

> runtime error 6. Overflow.

This error is pretty strange. I have been investigating it the last couple of days, here are the "facts" I have collected:

1) The error shows up only after the first call to the dll. All successive calls to this function don't cause this error.

2) The error is triggered by the first (seemingly harmless) floating-point instruction in the VBA code after the control returns from the dll:

```
Dim dMinValue As Double
dMinValue = 10000000#
```

3) The project from which the dll is built contains 4 files: mydll.cpp, mydll.def, cSomeClass.cpp and cSomeClass.h.

`cSomeClass` is a fairly complicated class that calls code from my other libs. BUT `mydll.cpp` does not use `cSomeClass` in any way. Here is the code of `mydll.cpp`:

```
#include <OAIdl.h>
#include <float.h>
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) 
{
  return TRUE;
}
extern "C" VARIANT WINAPI MyFunc()
{
  unsigned int u;
  u = _controlfp(0, 0);
  _controlfp(u & ~(_EM_INVALID | _EM_DENORMAL | _EM_ZERODIVIDE | _EM_OVERFLOW | _EM_UNDERFLOW | _EM_INEXACT), _MCW_EM);

  VARIANT res;
  memset(&res, 0, sizeof(VARIANT));
  ::VariantInit(&res);

  return res;
}
```

The initial version of `MyFunc()` didn't have the first 3 lines (the ones messing with `_controlfp()`), it was causing `"Runtime Error 6, Overflow"` in VBA. Then I started suspecting that this error could be related to the FPU registeres (I know very little about those). When I added these 3 lines an exception was thrown when I call `_controlfp()` -  `"0xC0000090: Floating-point invalid operation."`. If I leave the code as it is presented above the exception causes stack unwind (we don't get to the `VARIANT res;` line) and a window saying `"runtime error 6. Overflow."` is displayed in Excel. To sum it up, adding these 3 lines caused the floating point exception to be thrown earlier. If we catch the exception thrown in the 3rd line (with an `__except` clause) and ignore it (by callng `_clearfp()`) then no errors are reported in Excel.

A NASTY DETAIL: if I remove the files `cSomeClass.cpp` and `cSomeClass.h` from the Visual Studio project the error is not reproduced. `cSomeClass.h` is not includeed into `mydll.cpp`, but if I remove `cSomeClass.*` files from the project the dll size is significantly reduced.

My best guess at this point is that there are some static objects in the LIB-s referenced by `cSineClass.cpp` that cause this. Maybe these objects are initialized (constructed) when the dll is being loaded (according to my experiments, before to `DllMain`) and this somehow causes an error flag for `"0xC0000090: Floating-point invalid operation."` being set. When we return to Visual Basic from the dll, somethis calls `_controlfp` and enables the floating-point exceptions (they are turned off in С++) when raises `"0xC0000090: Floating-point invalid operation."` that somehow gets converted to `"Runtime Error 6. Overflow."` that I see in Excel. This is just a guess. Up unti now I haven't found any static objects that could be doing this.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to create a small example reproducing this error, because it shows up only when I have `cSomeFile.*` as part of the project. And those files require all of my libs...

If anyone knows what could be the cause of such behaviour or have suggestions about how to advance with my investigations that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: OK. I have narrowed the case down. It is caused by a static const double variable being initialized with numeric_limits<double>::infinity() in _CRT_INIT() - a function that is called before DllMain.
Can anyone explain what is happening here? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems to be caused by another variable being initialized with numeric_limits<double>::signaling_NaN().

Comment: Have you ever figured out how to resolve this problem?  I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

So I have at various points had similar random issues with Excel, and you are my hero.

I found that by calling `_clearfp()`, it will quiet the error and return the value properly.  I think the issue arises from the fact that I use `_HUGE` values all over the place to signify invalid floats.  Which sets the flag, and causes Excel (and only excel) to barf.  I've never run into any issues with runtime exceptions before in any other program.

Answer (score 1):

1) Apparently, when I get into the DLL code from VBA the FPU exceptions are turned off, like if someone called

```
  u = _controlfp( 0, 0 );
  _controlfp( u & ((_EM_INVALID | _EM_DENORMAL | _EM_ZERODIVIDE | _EM_OVERFLOW | _EM_UNDERFLOW | _EM_INEXACT )), _MCW_EM );
```

before passing control to my dll code.

2) Calling std::numeric_limits::signaling_NaN() at any point causes the _EM_INVALID flag to be set in the floating point status word (can be seen by calling _statusfp()).

3) When the control is returned from the DLL the FPU exceptions seem to be turned on. As if someone called:

```
  u = _controlfp( 0, 0 );
  _controlfp( u & (~(_EM_INVALID | _EM_DENORMAL | _EM_ZERODIVIDE | _EM_OVERFLOW | EM_UNDERFLOW | _EM_INEXACT )), _MCW_EM );
```

This causes a runtime error.